# Parsing A Table, Can't get more than 3 row Using DOMXpath

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

For some wierd reason that I can't understand right now I can't fetch more than 3 row from an table in a page

This is the page.

http://www.reedmfgco.com/en/products/cutters-and-cutter-wheels/cutter-wheels/cutter-wheels-for-tubing-cutters-plastic/

I want to parse the table at the bottom.

Since there is only one table in the page I made my Xpath really simple.`$xpath -> query('//tr')`

If I do the following

```
echo $xpath -> query('//tr')->lenght;
```

I get `3`

Why Am i getting `3` there is 9 row there, I should get `9`.

---

Edit
This is the code I Use

```
$Dom = new DOMDocument();
@$Dom -> loadHTML($this->html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($Dom);
echo $xpath -> query('//tr')->lenght;
```

And please note that $this->html  is the raw html from the previous link in my post.

Comment: What does your query look like and how to you walk through the results? We would really need to see some code.

Comment: there is not mutch code to show but let me a sec, Il update my post  But technicly the query you see that I echo is prety mutch the only query need to work corectly and it's not.

Comment: I spy a typo: lenght != lenght

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML source on this page is not valid for XML.
If you open the source code of the page and will look for a tag `<tr>`, it also has 3 elements.
Table row products do not have opening tag `<tr>`

For this problem, you can use regular expressions to normalize the contents of the table.

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.reedmfgco.com/en/products/cutters-and-cutter-wheels/cutter-wheels/cutter-wheels-for-tubing-cutters-plastic/');

preg_match('`<tbody>(.*)<\/tbody>`', $html, $matches);
if (!empty($matches)) {
    $tableBody = str_replace('</tr><td', '</tr><tr><td', $matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: Yeah,. I see that now..   Is there a way I can still parse a non valid html ?  or to fix it prior to xpath it?

Comment: I changed the answer and added an example